# What is the rationale for selecting the value "one" as the probability of sample space?

Tags: probability, axioms

Among the three axioms of the probability theory, the following is said to be the normalization axiom

$$p(\Omega) = 1$$

It states that the probability of the entire sample space ($\Omega$) is equal to one.

I want to know the rationale behind selecting the number "1".  Why not some other constant $c$?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a related question that may somewhat answer this one (one possible answer being "cleanliness of Theorem statements"): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402234/reference-for-independent-events-for-general-finite-measures

Comment: What fraction of the whole is occupied by the whole?

Comment: It is one hundred percent certain that something will happen. One hundred percent is one.

Comment: Aarons comment is the best one.

Answer (score 4):

If we take $\mathsf{P}(\Omega)=c>0$, then we can equivalently work with $\mathsf{P}'$ defined as $\mathsf{P}'(A):=\mathsf{P}(A)/c$. Besides that, taking $c=1$ is useful when defining product spaces because
$$
\mathsf{P}_2(\Omega\times \Omega)=\mathsf{P}(\Omega)\mathsf{P}(\Omega)=1.
$$
(Consider the issue when defining probabilities on the infinite product $\Omega^{\mathbb{N}}$ if $c\ne 1$.)